# 1998 jeep grand cherokee parasitic draw

Tags: jeep

My jeep has a parasitic draw I traced them back to my cluster, my cigar lighter, and my rear washer I took a part my dash and tried seeing if there were any bad wires I could not see any help would very much be appreciated. I how ever cannot pull those fuses seeing how I need them to drive.

Answer (score 1):

If it were a "bad wire", I'd assume you meant a dead short which would be much more likely to blow the fuse than drain the battery. If you still have the dash apart, it wouldn't be hard to disconnect the cluster and lighter to see if the draw still exists, would it? If there's still a draw it must be the rear washer. Else plug in the cluster or lighter and see if the draw appears. I'll take the cluster for 50¢, Alex.

Answer (score 1):

The draw may be isolated to one of these individual components. First unplug the rear windshield washer motor and see if draw goes away. If not plug it back in and repeat with the other 2 components. If unplugging one of these components eliminates the excessive draw you have found the faulty component. If not then you may have a short somewhere. But a component check is a good place to start.

Comment: ok thanks you although it couldn't be the cluster could it? because all my gauges still all work perfect and my cigar works also and my componentes when unplugged or fuse pulled the excessive draw does go away

Comment: If you pull the fuse and the excessive draw goes away, the fault is in one ore more of the components in that fused circuit. So yes it could be any one of those components, or it could be a positive to positive short from another circuit.